# Why do I not see a login option for the guest at the login screen?

Tags: greeter

I have just installed Elementary OS 5 in a virtual machine.

Since I am a fan of guest user login I checked the user account settings and noticed that guest login is enabled by default. However, when I log off I do not see a login option for the guest user at the login screen. The only option to log in as a guest is to enable the automatic login for the guest user and then reboot the machine.

Why do I not see a login option for the guest at the login screen?